# How to get small caps in Classico (texlive 2014)?

Tags: fonts, texlive, macports

After installing texlive 2014 (via macports) all my documents using the "Classico" font stopped compiling. I scratched my head for a while (RTFM, STFW), and then I discovered that I should not invoke the font with this any more:

```
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{hop}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

but now I'm now supposed to write this instead:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{classico}
```

And indeed, with this I can compile *some* documents. But my problem remains, because pdflatex still chokes on small caps ( `\textsc{}` ) and maybe other things.

My question is: **What did I do wrong ?**

Post scriptum:

- minimal not-working example: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cZKMq0bc
- pdflatex console output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xBYf0mfm
- pdflatex log: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p90EqFbq

Comment: I justed tested using `TL14` fully updated on Linux, compiles just fine. Why are you installing via `macports` instead of just using `MacTeX`? If `macports` fragment TL as Ubuntu does, it might be that you are missing some packages or that the `.map` file for classico has not been enabled.

Comment: The Classico font support has changed and the family name is not `uop` any more. One of course need installing it manually or with `getnonfreefonts-sys`.

Comment: Just noticed that too, I've installed classico using `getnonfreefonts-sys`, remember you have to download and install getnonfreefonts first, see https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Comment: Yes, I did the `getnonfreefonts` thing, but I suspect it to be somehow outdated, as it goes to CTAN and fetches a file called `getfont2013`. Could that be (part of) the problem ?

Comment: @egreg Is a newer version available? I reinstalled for 2014 and it seems to use `uop` for pdfTeX. (It now uses the truetype for XeTeX/LuaTeX.)

Comment: @cfr If you installed it with `getnonfreefonts-sys` and run  `getnonfreefonts-sys -l` you'll see that a newer version is available. The Type1 fonts have been rebuilt from the OpenType version with `otftotfm`, with the usual impact on the name of the `.tfm` files (long names instead of Berry ones).

Comment: @daleif: I'm used to macports, and so far it served me well, so I never looked at mactex. but should I ? and BTW I assume my system is up-to-date, since the version number for my `classico.sty` is 2014-06-26.

Comment: @Gyom I have the same version

Comment: @daleif: I contacted the author of `classico.sty`, who suggested the problem was that I _hadn't enabled the Map file classico.map_. However, `udpmap-sys --listmaps` does display it as "enabled" ! [(updmap transcript)](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=n9rDaz0G). I'm stuck.

Comment: Are those pastebin files fully up to date, and what happens if you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as the first package in the example?

Comment: What does `kpsewhich classico.map` return?

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` does change the `.fd` file which gets loaded (`T1URWClassico-LF.fd` vs `OT1URWClassico-LF.fd`) but that's all I notice.

Comment: `kpsewhich classico.map` returns `/opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/classico/classico.map` which contains this: http://pastebin.com/H8RL46zY

Comment: How about the `.pfb` files, can `kpsewhich` find those, e.g. `kpsewhich  uopr8a.pfb`

Comment: `kpsewhich uopr8a.pfb` prints `/opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/type1/urw/classico/uopr8a.pfb` (I understand this is the expected output)

Comment: Well. It turns out that my problem was due to a bug in the packaging of the font (some files were missing). The author of classico.sty has uploaded a new version (2014-08-03) to CTAN, and now everything just works great.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem turned out to be caused by bug, and the bug has since been fixed.